# Search all files except a certain file type in NetBeans?

Tags: file-management, netbeans

With NetBeans, how can I search for text within all files except for a certain file type?

I have an option called **"File name patterns"**, but I can't see how to exclude a certain file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Find in Project** dialog below *File Name Patterns* you can see an check box for **Use Ignore List**.After checking the box the edit link is visible,in that dialogue you can Add Path pattern for file type.
Eg: `*.java,*.jsp`. So that the netbeans ignore specified file type.